# Cleaner way to write api route handlers in NextJS

Tags: express, next.js

Currently most of the api route handlers are in the following shape(`api/test.js`):

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    // Process a POST request
  } else {
    // Handle any other HTTP method
  }
}
```

where we constantly compare `req.method` with `if`s

Is there a way to write it similar to ExpressJS:

```
app.get(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';

const handler = nextConnect();
//handler.use(middleware);

handler.get(async (req, res) => { 
  ...your code
})
...
handler.post(async (req, res) => { 
  ...your code
})
...
```

So in theory you can have `/api/product` where you have `.get .post .delete` (etc) in 1 api route

*`Clean`* solution (`/api/product.js`)

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
   
   try {

   }

   catch(e){
   
   }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without this module?

Comment: Not sure, but if you like to work with no module you will need to code patterns and handlers for API.